# How to play swf video url in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-video-player

In my application, I want to display this video which is from the following url: `http://74.208.194.142/songoware_btn_btg.swf`.

Please, help me how to display this video. I am not able to understand which process I should follow.

Thank you.